# How to install and setup thumbor

Tags: python, image, cdn, cloudinary, thumbor

I found an image hosting python project on the internet named [thumbor](http://thumbor.org/), I believe its self-hosted, and their [documentation](https://thumbor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html) is pretty straightforward. I didn't get all the process required to install and set up the server and start hosting images through API.

if anyone setted up this service before, please help me, guide me through the process, please!

of if u guys know any free image hosting and CDN service, you can suggest me. like cloudinary, but a little more free to use, coz I need to develop a simple user management site!

Comment: I recently set Thumbor up on AWS Cloudfront + S3 + Lambda following this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/overview.html.

Comment: I'm using google cloud platform. is it possible?

Comment: No idea, but with AWS it was pretty straightforward to set up, so far it has cost pence. Just added it here in case it was helpful.

Comment: yes, i'll also try that with AWS. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently used thumbor for personal projects :
The easiest step to get thumbor working is to clone the repo from [GitHub](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor),

Install it using setup.py & then start it using the command

```
thumbor -p 8000
```

this will help you start the server at port number 8000 & then you can serve the requests using

```
http://<thumbor-server>:PORT_NUMBER/300x200/smart/s.glbimg.com/et/bb/f/original/2011/03/24/VN0JiwzmOw0b0lg.jpg
```

I hope this helps you. In case you are stuck, feel free to ask.

You can also go through the following [PDF](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/thumbor/latest/thumbor.pdf) to further understanding.

Comment: I've allocated the domain to the server, can I access it with domain? If yes can I run the thumbor in Port 80 so that I don't have to use port while accessing the image! Btw thank you for your reply

Comment: You should either start a new instance & use the IP provided to hit thumbor server else you can have thumbor on your server instance with a different port number.

Comment: Ok ok. Got it. Tysm